# Accessing webpage hosted in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Host: Ubuntu 13.10

Guest: Ubuntu VM VirtualBox 4.3.10

Server: Both Nginx

Level: Beginner

Virtual Machine Network Setup: Adapter 1 = NAT, Adapter 2 = Host-only adapter

**What i want to do:**
Access webpage from Virtual Machine.
Everything in VirtualBox was properly setup. I just need to setup my nginx settings to access the webpage.

This is my hosts file:
127.0.0.1       chao.local    >> This is a wordpress website in my local

I added 192.168.56.1    gge.vm
to my hosts file, which is the webpage in my virtual machine but when I'm trying gge.vm in my browser, it's being redirected to chao.local.

Is there anything else i need to configure to run gge.vm?